# java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected void java.net.URLClassLoader.addURL(java.net.URL) accessible

Tags: java

This exception is being thrown; how to fix it?

```
java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected void java.net.URLClassLoader.addURL(java.net.URL) accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.net" to unnamed module @338aec90
        at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.checkCanSetAccessible(Method.java:199) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.setAccessible(Method.java:193) ~[?:?]
        at net.byteflux.libby.classloader.URLClassLoaderHelper.<init>(URLClassLoaderHelper.java:37) ~[LifeSteal-1.0.jar:?]
        at net.byteflux.libby.BukkitLibraryManager.<init>(BukkitLibraryManager.java:28) ~[LifeSteal-1.0.jar:?]
        at in.arcadelabs.lifesteal.handler.DependencyHandler.<init>(DependencyHandler.java:18) ~[LifeSteal-1.0.jar:?]
        at in.arcadelabs.lifesteal.LifeStealPlugin.onLoad(LifeStealPlugin.java:39) ~[LifeSteal-1.0.jar:?]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_19_R1.CraftServer.loadPlugins(CraftServer.java:425) ~[purpur-1.19.jar:git-Purpur-1670]
        at net.minecraft.server.dedicated.DedicatedServer.initServer(DedicatedServer.java:313) ~[purpur-1.19.jar:git-Purpur-1670]
        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.runServer(MinecraftServer.java:1137) ~[purpur-1.19.jar:git-Purpur-1670]
        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.lambda$spin$1(MinecraftServer.java:307) ~[purpur-1.19.jar:git-Purpur-1670]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[?:?]
```

I am using a dependency manager library called libby (https://github.com/Byteflux/libby) so when I call `LibraryManager libraryManager = new BukkitLibraryManager();` it thows exception

Comment: Seems like "libby" hasn't been updated to work with newer versions of Java. But you could try running the code with `--add-opens=java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED`.

Comment: It looks like this fork may have addressed the issue ... https://github.com/AlessioDP/libby

Comment: [This Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48041764) gives some background on what "libby" was apparently trying to do.  This is the kind of thing that JEP 260 and JEP 396 are intended to stop.

Comment: The origin of my problems is different, but @Slaw 's solution solved my case.  Thank you.  Just to leave a breadcrumb here, in case someone faces the same problem as mine, I'm trying to run an Eclipse RCP application using "java -jar plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_*.jar", as mentioned here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/479598/431

Answer (score 6):

did you upgrade your JDK / JRE lately?

I had that same error message, when I downgrade to older Java version it was fixed.

Comment: you can check your Gradle version as well. I changed the updated version in gradle-wrapper.properties file and inside the project level, Gradle file and that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Open gradle-wrapper.properties, and update the distributionUrl to the latest version.

For example,
update

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.1-bin.zip
```

to

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.3.3-bin.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my case:

**Reason:**
I updated my AS, it uses jdk17 by default which caused the problem

**Solution:**
Change "gradle jdk location" in your AS, use your lower version jdk like jdk11 solved my problem